# How much cpu/memory/storage at least I need to use ELK

Tags: elastic-stack, elk

Our project has requirement for log aggregation of different micro-services, and ELK is great tool to do that. However our project has requirement of privatization deployment, which means we need to deploy the whole solution into customers' own servers. Based on this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC4GGJ0JsSE), ELK has pre-requisites of at least 2GB RAM and at least 20GB storage, is this always the situation? If yes, then ELK is a little resource consuming, which may not quite fit to our privatization deployment situation. Create this issue and would like to get advise and suggestion about whether I should choose ELK for privatization deployment scenario for log aggregation.

Answer (score 4):

If we deep dive into all three stacks are Elastic Search, Logstash and Kibana

**LOGSTASH**

- Logstash’s biggest con or “Achille’s heel” has always been performance and resource consumption (the default heap size is 1GB).
- Though performance improved a lot over the years, it’s still a lot slower than the alternatives
- Best alternatives for logstash are rsyslog, filebeat and fluentd. last two are really nice in terms of docker environment and log aggeration. consumption is less compared to logstash

**ELASTIC SEARCH**

- Elasticsearch is a distributed, RESTful search and analytics engine capable of storing data and searching it in near real time.
- Since this deals with Indexing and search operations on top that, yes the CPU consumption is gonna be high.
- It is better to use Solr and Lucene based on your business case as the both serves same purpose.
- The best suggestion i can give is to use Splunk. I pass the ball to your court to implement it.

**KIBANA**

- Kibana is just a visualisation tool. I haven't experienced it consumes high CPU
- Again we have best alternatives here like **Grafana** and **Promethus** which is really good compared to Kibana.

Hope this helps you.